# How to display the head to the left

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I trying to display the alphabets here to the left of each row of the channel listing. How do I go about doing that       ?

```
<div class="w3-container w3-threequarter">
    <ul class="w3-ul w3-card-1" *ngFor="let head of channelDisplayHeads" >
     <h1 align="center" style="background-color:#0083BC"><font color="white">{{ head }}</font></h1>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let channel of channelList">
        <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay" *ngIf="channel.channel.substr(0, 1) === head">
            <img class="w3-image" src= "{{ channel.logo }}" align="center" alt="{{ channel.channel }}" width="80" height="80"><br>
            <!-- <span align="center"><strong><font size="2">{{ channel.channel }}</font></strong></span><br> -->
          <span class="w3-left"><mark><font size="1">{{ channel.cbsCode }}</font></mark></span><span class="w3-sand w3-right" style="text-shadow:0.2px 0.2px 0 #444"><font size="2">{{ channel.pickCode }}</font></span>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here how I got it so far. I need the "A", "B","C" to the left of each row. Please advise!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is your solution:**

```
.w3-ul > h1{
width: 40px;
float: left;
}
.logoDisplay{
float: left;
}
```

Or,

```
.w3-ul > h1, .logoDisplay{
display: inline-block; // if need use !important
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On each header row you just need to do a

```
text-align: left
```

In your css your header row should be something like this

```
<h1 style="background-color:#0083BC; text-align:left;"><font color="white">{{ head }}</font></h1>
```

I have just included the suggested style on the end of the inline styles you already had.

Also probably you don’t need the align: center

**Edit**

To move the header letters to the left of the channels rows you can float them or use flexbox

If you stick with the simple solution of floating them you just need to do

```
<h1 style="background-color:#0083BC; width:80px;float:left;"><font color="white">{{ head }}</font></h1>
```

I’m setting the width to 80px in case you wanted them to match the current width of each channel item, although I would suggest moving these inline styles to a dedicated class

And then on the list of channels styles

```
 .list-group-item {
    float:left;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Hugo Noro. Just didn't get it quite right. Could you explain please with some code examples?

Comment: Hello all, thanks for the speedy response, but that was not the way I am looking for. I am trying to have it on the same row of the channels once on the very left

Comment: Oh OK that’s a bit different. It wasn’t very clear. I’ll edit my answer in that case

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
<h1 align="center" style="background-color:#0083BC"><font color="white">{{ head }}</font></h1>
```

should be:

```
<h1 style="background-color:#0083BC; text-align: left;"><font color="white">{{ head }}</font></h1>
```

i.e. add `text-align: left;` remove `align: center`

Answer (score 1):

remove `align="center"` from `<h1>` and add `text-align: left`

Try this

```
<h1 style="background-color:#0083BC; text-align: left"><font color="white">{{ head }}</font></h1>
```