# Angular HTML formatting error

Tags: html, angular

This is with reference to the question I posted yesterday
[Link to yesterday's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806581/how-to-display-the-head-to-the-left)
Everything worked, But having issue breaking the rows now. As in the picture below the row "G" has "H" & "I" on the same row. Just trying how to have every alphabet and its channels on its own row. I have attached the HTML too at the bottom.
Please advise.
[image: Screenshot of the result]

```
<div class="w3-container w3-threequarter">
  <ul class="w3-ul w3-card-1" *ngFor="let head of channelDisplayHeads">
    <h1 align="center" style="background-color:#0083BC;">
      <font color="white">{{ head }}</font>
    </h1>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let channel of channelList">
      <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay" *ngIf="channel.channel.substr(0, 1) === head">
        <img class="w3-image" src="{{ channel.logo }}" align="center" alt="{{ channel.channel }}" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">{{ channel.cbsCode }}</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">{{ channel.pickCode }}</font>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just trying to have each alphabet and its channels in its own row.

Comment: you can set `width:100%;` or  try `w3-card-12`

Comment: On what part of the code I set that?

Comment: in your ul tag change class to `w3-card-12`

Comment: w3-card-12 didn't work, I set it on the ul class.

Comment: add  `style="clear:both"` in your ul tag

Comment: @Chris Happy I have posted answer its works fine  but I did get an upvote  from you working link https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/xpGyzq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working copy of above question @Chris Happy  and @Sumchans https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/xpGyzq

```css
.w3-ul > h1{
width: 40px;
float: left;
}
.logoDisplay{
float: left;
}


.w3-ul > h1, .logoDisplay{
display: inline-block; // if need use !important
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="w3-container">

<ul class="w3-ul w3-card-12" style="clear:both" >
   <h1 align="center" style="background-color:#0083BC;">
      <font color="white">heading</font>
    </h1>
     <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
</ul>
<ul class="w3-ul w3-card-1" style="clear:both">
   <h1 align="center" style="background-color:#0083BC;">
      <font color="white">heading</font>
    </h1>
     <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
  <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
</ul>
<ul class="w3-ul w3-card-1" style="clear:both">
   <h1 align="center" style="background-color:#0083BC;">
      <font color="white">heading</font>
    </h1>
     <li class="list-group-item logoDisplay">
       <img class="w3-image" src="logo" align="center" alt="channel" width="80" height="80">
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">code</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-sand w3-right">
          <font size="2">pickcode</font>
        </span>
     </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks for providing an example code snippet as well. Also just checking certain alphabets have more channels so they get stacked up at the bottom when they hit the width limit, how do I display them by not getting them into the column of the alphabets?